# Why is this question about science on Venus off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Why is the question [With no acid cloud deck surrounding Venus, would the poles be much colder than the equator ?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/with-no-acid-cloud-deck-surrounding-venus-would-the-poles-be-much-colder-then-t) put on hold as **off-topic**?
Isn't the question about planetary science and as such **on-topic** ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it is not off-topic. It is firmly within the scope of planetary science which we allow here. We get a lot of questions mistakenly asked here that belong at Astronomy, and this one happens to also be on topic there, so users sometimes err on the side of marking off topic too quickly. That said, there were some other points raised in the comments to be addressed with the question, so rather than reopen I changed the close reason to "too broad", which is what I believe uhoh voted for.